# How can I use url lib using a json file

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib2

I'm trying to get data from a json link, but I'm getting this error: TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

This is my code:

```
l = "https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/men/products/omch016f18d471431088s"
url = (l+".json"+"?porcoiddio")
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

size_opts = json.loads(response.decode('utf-8'))['available_sizes']
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: what are your headers here? could you provide all code?

Comment: @deif headers = {
    'Referer': 'https://www.off---white.com/it/IT/login',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'
    }

Comment: how can you get json data,the website seem to using javascrip to detect if you are using browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question answer is change your code to:

```
size_opts = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))['available_sizes']
```

Change at 2018-10-02 22:55 : I view your source code and found `Response 503` , the reason why you got 503 is that request did not contain cookies:

```
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
```

you have update your headers.

```
headers.update({"Cookie":cookie_value})
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers) # !!!! you need a headers include cookies !!!!
```

Comment: because this cookie is associated with your network environment , first website response 503 and let you wait for 5 second to check if you are accessing with browser , then using javascrip to create url  by your begining cookies , this url will reset your cookies. btw how did you get json on your code(your question) @ChefTraian i think i should edit my post to let you know how it work? (i think you need selenium because it is very difficult to do without using javascrip)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/gs3UnkUX here all my code, when cloudflare is offline on site works, when is on I get 503

Comment: @ChefTraian i have run your code and fixed it, this is the code after fixed https://pastebin.com/rKJT2SNQ , btw you have a right choice , cfscrape is better than selenium as solution

Answer (score 0):

You could have a go using requests instead?

```
import requests, json
l = "https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/men/products/omch016f18d471431088s"
url = (l+".json"+"?porcoiddio")
session = requests.Session()
session.mount('http://', requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=10))
size_opts = session.get(url, headers= {'Referer': 'off---white.com/it/IT/login', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'}).json()['available_sizes']
```

To check the response:

```
size_opts = session.get(url, headers= {'Referer': 'off---white.com/it/IT/login', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'})
print(size_opts)
```

Gives

```
<Response [503]>
```

This response means:  "503 Service Unavailable. The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overload or scheduled maintenance"

I would suggest the problem isn't the code but the server?

Comment: Getting this error: raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Sorry did you ```import json```

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: Its returning 503 Service Unavailable. The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overload or scheduled maintenance

Answer (score 0):

you are providing the data argument by mistake …

you'll have to use a keyword argument for headers as otherwise the second argument will be filled with positional input, which happens to be *data*, try this:

```
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request for a documentation of *Request*s signature.